# How do I get the jQuery datepicker to load properly on my Rails page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my Rails project I currently have the following:

```
= f.label :created_at_gteq
= f.text_field :created_at_gteq, { :class => "ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" }
= f.label :created_at_lteq
= f.text_field :created_at_lteq, { :class => "ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" }
```

Which generates the following:

```
<label for="q_created_at_gteq">Created at greater than or equal to</label>
<input class="ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" id="q_created_at_gteq" name="q[created_at_gteq]" size="30" type="text">
<label for="q_created_at_lteq">Created at less than or equal to</label>
<input class="ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" id="q_created_at_lteq" name="q[created_at_lteq]" size="30" type="text">
```

In my application.js I have the following:

```
//Makes calendar UI popup on date fields
$(function () {
  // Initializers and variables
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  console.log($('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker());
});
```

The following is returned in my javascript console when the page is loaded:

```
[<input class=​"ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" id=​"q_created_at_gteq" name=​"q[created_at_gteq]​" size=​"30" type=​"text">​
, 
<input class=​"ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" id=​"q_created_at_lteq" name=​"q[created_at_lteq]​" size=​"30" type=​"text">​]
```

Before the end of the body tag, the following HTML is inserted:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

So I know that its finding the correct inputs and it even looks like its attempting to add the datapicker to the DOM, however the div that is being added is missing all the content inside the div as well as the inline styles that position it correctly, so the datepicker doesn't show up when I click in the date fields.

Any idea why its returning the datepicker incorrectly?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems an issue with the multiple classes with the input element.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ffwr2/4/

Removed the hasDatepicker for the first element and it worked fine.
Whereas, the second still doesn't work.
Remove for both and both should work.